# can't display background image HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm using a LAMP installation to create some personal sites.
I just can't understand why i won't be able to put a background image in the body section of my site.

Either if I use css or simple HTML when i try to put an image as background the result will be a blank page, or colored if I set a background color.

```
<body background="./image.jpg"> 

    <p>hello</p> 

</body>
```

or

index.html:

```
<head> 

     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

</head>

<body> 

    <p>hello</p> 

</body>
```

style.css:

```
body { 
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    background-image: url(./image.jpg); 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #787878; 
}
```

Any ideas on what i could be doing wrong?

Maybe there's some kind of module to activate in order to visualize images?

Any help will be very appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Don't you need `../` instead of `./`?

Comment: Are you sure that your image reference (./image.jpg) is correct and that the image is accessible from the web?

Comment: the path is ok.the dot means current directory

Comment: the image is not accessible from the web, i'm working in local. shouldn't it work?

Comment: if the image is in the same folder as the html and css, get rid of the `./`

Comment: It is, but actually i added it later, cause it wouldn't work with just the name. However it didn't change anything with or without.

Comment: @Matteo That depends what you mean my "working in local". If you're using a `file://...` URL in the browser, and the browser can see the image file okay using a `file://...` path too, then it should be okay. If you're using a local web server (i.e. `http://...`, then the image must be exposed on that web server at least as much as the HTML file is...)

Comment: @Matt - I'm using a local web server but I'm kind of a newbie..could you please explain me a little better how should I expose the image?just putting it in the same directory of the html file is not ok?

Comment: @Matteo Given your code, you should put it in the same directory as the HTML file, yes. You must also make sure that your web server has permission to read the file -- giving it the same file permissions as your HTML file should be a good start. (How you do that depends on what OS you're using.)

Comment: [SOLVED] it was a permission problem..giving all privileges to the file turned out to work..thks a lot!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tips for debugging and other info, which should hopefully lead you to the correct answer:

- Check to see if you can see the image directly in your web browser. If the path you're using to the HTML file is, for example, "http://example.com/some/dir/index.html", then browse directly to "http://example.com/some/dir/image.jpg" and see if the image appears. If it doesn't, then your image is inaccessible, or in the wrong place, or possibly corrupt or being served with the wrong Content-Type.
- If the image is in the right place but seems inaccessible, check the file permissions first. The file should be readable by the web server. If in doubt, give it the same ownership and permissions as the HTML file you're successfully reading. (On Windows, view the properties/permissions of the file and allow everyone to read it. On Unix, try chmod 644 `<filename>`.)
- Consider the possibility that the image might actually be working fine, but also be a single pixel, or completely transparent, or a plain colour the same as its background, or positioned out of sight with the CSS positioning attributes.
- Try temporarily using another image, preferably one you can definitely see on the web in the web browser you're using for testing, downloaded with that browser (that will make sure there are no weird problems with the image file itself.)
- Remember that if you're defining the background in a CSS file, the path to the image is relative to that CSS file, not to the HTML file.
- The "background" attribute is deprecated in HTML. If you want to specify a background inline in the HTML, try `<body style="background-image: url(image.jpg);" >...</body>`. But the proper place for this would be in the CSS these days.
- You don't need "./" in front of your image location. If it's in the same directory as your HTML file, just use the name of the image, e.g. `<body style="background-image: url(image.jpg);">`
- Does it work as a plain image? `<img src="background.jpg"/>`
- Sanity-check your HTML by using a very simple, valid test document, like this one:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);">
        This is a test.
    </body>`

Comment: 6) it is not visualized as a plain image. The result will be a little square with a broken page in it.

5)ok, I removed it, but still won't work..

4) just tried for debugging, I am using CSS.

3) the 2 files are in the same directory, so relative path is the same am I correct?

2)Tried using a real url of an image on the web, but it would give me the same problem.

1)The image I'm using is saved on my hard drive, and is not loaded on the web, is this the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply your path is not correct, also it might be easier for you to use a link like:

`background-image: url(/images/image.jpg);`

which would refer to WEBROOT then images folder.
Use tools like Firebug of Chromes Inspector to find why the image doesn't load, its clearly a bad path to your image.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to remember that the background-image is being set from the CSS file, therefore the path to the image is relative to the location of the CSS file, not the HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and it was because of my file structure

Normally we have :

index.html

Images (folder)
      - image1.jpg

css(folder)
      - style.css

So, in order to get the path to access image1.jpg, you need to go up one folder. In the style.css file you will write 
`../Images/image1.jpg`

instead of 
`./Images/image1.jpg`

This was how I did it. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in the same directory, the rule should be

```
background-image: url('image.jpg');
```

NB: you may need to add the quotes above.

Comment: I tried every kind of combination of syntax before posting for help, and it will never work. I think the problem maybe in some visualization module not activated, is it possible?

Comment: Check to see if the image shows on the page if you add it as an element in the body, e.g. `<img src="" />`.

Comment: I tried, it will not visualize it. But this time the result is the little window with the broken page in it..what does it mean?

Comment: That means your image is not where you think it is or that you have named it incorrectly. 1. make sure it is in the same folder as the css stylesheet. 2. make sure it is named/spelled the same.  This include use of lower- and uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are on your website, then A workaround could be to write the absolute path to the images on your website - That works both on local host and on your website.

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
background-image: url('img/image.jpg');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17171408)

Comment: @Sergey What makes you think that it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Lundin, this answer doesn't provide any description: "why this code works?", "why I need use this sample instead of any other answers for this post?". Just _use the following_ - this description for comments only

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and could never find a definitive solution. In my case I needed to add **file:///** before the local path. That did the trick. So in css you would have something like:

background-image: url("file:///C:/Users.../resources/images/img-story-main.png");

If you're using atom, you can copy the full path to the img and paste on your browser. It will include the file///
That's how i figured it out.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. When you deploy your website, the local path is invalid.  Let's say your css file in "project/css/file.css", and your image is in "project/image/img.png". Then the path in css should be "../image/img.png".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way to do it 
https://codepen.io/CITSimon/pen/QNZOmP

## HTML

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <H1>My Heading On An Image</H1>
  <IMG SRC="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/ripe-red-apple-green-leaf-600w-1669348621.jpg" alt="apple" />
</BODY>
<HTML>
```

## CSS

```
h1{
  font-size : 50px;
}
img{
  position : absolute;
  left : 0px;
  top : 0px;
  z-index : -1;
  -webkit-filter : sepia(100%) opacity(0.5);
  filter : sepia(100%) opacity(0.5);;
}
```

[image: Heading on an image]